# How to pass enum argument via reflection in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to pass an enum constant as an argument to a method via reflection. Here is a simple example that demonstrates a very simplified version of my problem. (Assume I must use reflection)

```
enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY
}

public class Main {

    public void print(Day d) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Class<?> cl = Class.forName("Day");
        Field field = cl2.getDeclaredField("MONDAY");
        print(_what_to_pass_here?)
    }
}
```

How do I do it?

Thanks,

Comment: [`Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum<?>>)cl, "MONDAY")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to access the field directly. Use `Enum.valueOf()`:

```
Enum.valueOf(cl.asSubclass(Day.class), "MONDAY")
```

But it's hard to see why you couldn't use `Day.class` directly. It might help to elaborate on your use case.

Comment: @BoristheSpider But you have to know the enum type to call `print()`. Unless you want to call that reflectively too.

Answer (score 1):

Try `java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Object obj)`:

```
Day day = (Day) field.get(cl);
print(day);
```